# Parse Oracle Query using perl

Tags: sql, perl, oracle, parsing, lexical-analysis

I have to perform lexical analysis on the oracle query and separate the query to various parts (based on the clauses)in perl. For example,Consider :

```
Select deleteddate,deletedby from temptable where id = 10;
```

I need to print

```
select : deleteddate , deletedby
from : temptable
where : id = 10
```

I used this code snippet :

```
my $parser= SQL::Statement->new();
$parser->{PrinteError}=1;
my $query = SQL::Statement->new("select deleteddate,deletedby from temptable where id =10",$parser);

my @columns = $query->columns();

print $columns[0]->name();
```

Though this prints deleteddate, this fails when i give a subquery inside the select clause:

```
Select deleteddate,deletedby,(select 1+1 from dual) from temptable where id = 10;
```

Can you please point me in the correct direction.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to be a limitation of that package; it seems to be a general purpose parser and not something that can understand advanced features like subqueries or Oracle-specific constructs like "from dual".

What are the constraints of your system? If python is an option it looks like this is a more fully-featured library:

http://code.google.com/p/python-sqlparse/

The other option would be to use the actual Oracle database, if that's an option. You would:

- use the DBI and DBD::Oracle modules to create a connection to Oracle & get a database handle,
- create a statement handle by calling prepare() on the database handle using your query,
- execute the query (there may be an option in Oracle to execute in "test only" or "parse only" mode),
- examine the statement handle (such as the NAMES_hash property) to get the column names.

Otherwise it seems the SQL::Statement module unfortunately just isn't up to the task...